# In spoken English, is it okay to ask questions without putting it in the reverse order?

Tags: questions, word-order, informal-language, spoken-english

In spoken English, do we always need to say, for example, "Is there any problem with it?" or can we ask questions just like "There is any problem with it?". I'm living in the UK and sometimes seems that natives speak in a direct order and even suppressed do/does in some questions.

Comment: We usually reverse the word order, or reduce the question to an abbreviated form:  "Any problems?"  Sometimes we might say (ask) "There a problem here?" with a rising intonation.  But that's not purely a question, it's a suggestion that the speaker doesn't want there to be a problem, like a warning.

Comment: This is called an "echo question". It was mentioned in this [answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/19581/3281), this [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/40568/3281), and this [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/32233/3281).

Answer (score 0):

If using "Is" or "Are" you have to put it in front
An "Is", "are", "were", "was" is formed like this

> is(Is", "are", "were", "was")+article+verb+...